# NSFetchedResultsController one entity for sections and a different entitiy for rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have two entities that I am working with. `Video` and `Category`. Categories have many videos and videos have only one category.

I want to use `NSFetchedResultsController` to display the videos for each category in a UITableView. So the sections in the `UITableView` would be representing Categories. The rows of the `UITableView` would be representing videos in a particular category.

I have only used `NSFetchedResultsController` with one entity and I'm wondering if it is possible to do what I want to do with `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Yes if you have relation ship with categories...you can give sectionKey category

Comment: agree with C_X, if you have a foreign key on your video objects for the categories you should be able to do this.  Otherwise you'd have to get each category one at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that if there is a relationship. Consider you have ManagedObject `Video` and if relationship is set then video will have an attribute `Category`. So you can use category as section, but one thing `sectionNameKeyPathv` should be a string. I hope `Category` will have an attribue `name`, you can use that like this `Category.name` as `sectionNameKeyPath` while creating `NSFetchResultController`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do as C_x suggests and it  would work although re-fetching the section objects might get messy.

Another option is to build your own `NSFetchedResultsController` replacement.  There is not a lot of work in it and then you can control everything yourself.